# How to create a hyperlink to file in shared network directory in Microsoft Teams Incoming WebHook?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to send a working link to a file in Windows shared folder with Incoming WebHook? E.g. a link to\DESKTOP-HRQNAF6\Test.zip?

I use a PowerShell to send messages to Teams:

```
$body = '{"text":"<b>Download:</b></br><ul><li><a href=\"\\\\DESKTOP-HRQNAF6\\Temp\\Test.zip\">Test</a></li></ul>"}'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $connectorUri -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

But the link is blank:

[image]

I also tried to use such a link: file://desktop-hrqnaf6/Temp/Test.zip, but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

@Aneha, Connectors supports three different action ActionCard/HttpPost/openUri using which you can send the url. Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#creating-actionable-messages) for more details.

Comment: I already tried to use different types of actions, but every time, the button just disappears when I use the file link or URL to the share. I can not find information on how to add a link to a file in a message in the documentation. It seems like the only solution is to use sharepoint as storage, but this is weird.